# ParserError: Expected '{' but got 'memory'

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, evm

Am using `pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;`.

Line `42` with the below function:

```
function addXtoAccName( address _accNumber, string _xtoName ) public memory {
        accounts[_accNumber].xtoDisplayName = _xtoName;
        accounts[_accNumber].xtoAccNumber = _accNumber;
}
```

is causing this error message:

```
ParserError: Expected '{' but 
got 'memory'
:
:
42 | function addXtoAccName(
address _accNumber, string 
_xtoName ) public membory {
| ^^^^^^
```

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong on line 42?

Comment: What is `memory` ? Is it a modifier ? Can you show your complete code please ? The form of a function is the following : `function function_name(<param_type> <param_name>) <visibility> <state mutability> [returns(<return_type>)]{ ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses the `memory` keyword in the modifier section of the function definition, where it doesn't belong. Also, it's missing the [data location](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html#data-location) for the `string` argument. All reference types (including `string`) need to define their data location.

So it seems that you just misplaced the `memory` keyword.

Note just in case if you were aiming to intentionally use a modifier named `memory`: It's a reserved keyword, so it's not possible to use a modifier with this name.

---

**Solution:** Move the `memory` keyword after the `string`:

```
function addXtoAccName( address _accNumber, string memory _xtoName ) public {
```